# Getting data from multiple tables with relationship

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

[image]

I want to select a specific users movies with the title and the genre.

What i tried:

```
select title, name 
from movies 
left join genres on movies.id=genres.id 
left join users on movies.id=users.id;
```

And returns me all the movies of all the users

Comment: You haven't specified a particular user, so why shouldn't it show all the movies of all users? How is it supposed to know which particular user you want?

Comment: Add `WHERE users.username = ?` and specify the username in the parameters.

Comment: @Barmar i tried adding WHERE users.username = "admin" and return 0 rows, when it should return 2

Comment: You need to use the `users_movies` table to find the relationship between users and movies.

Comment: And you need to use `movies_genres` to find the genres of movies.

Comment: Please share sample data with create table and insert script. Also, share the output you are expecting from sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the tables `users_movies` and `movies_genres` to find the relationships between users, movies, and genres.

```
SELECT m.title, g.name
FROM movies AS m
JOIN movies_genres AS mg ON m.id = mg.movies_id
JOIN genres AS g ON g.id = mg.genres_id
JOIN users_movies AS um ON m.id = um.movies_id
JOIN users AS u ON u.id = um.users_id
WHERE u.username = 'admin'
```

Example of how to fill in these tables:

```
INSERT INTO movies (title, year, description, image, runtime, rating)
VALUES ("Test", 1999, "All about a test", "", 120, 1);
SET @movie_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO genres (name) VALUES ('horror');
SET @genre_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ("admin", "adminpw");
SET @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO movies_genres (movies_id, genres_id)
VALUES (@movie_id, @genre_id);

INSERT INTO users_movies (movies_id, users_id)
VALUES (@movie_id, @user_id);
```

Comment: It's still return 0 rows

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Post it as plain text, not screenshots. Or make a sqlfiddle.

Comment: [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/xcuyv6N) photos with the code, tables and result. I deleted all tables content and added new data to them, and it still returns 0 rows

Comment: I can't copy/paste a photo.

Comment: You don't show the `movies_users` and `movies_genres` tables in your screenshot.

Comment: those tables have only foreign keys referencing to ex: user_id of the movie_id, and currently they don't have any values in them

Comment: You need to fill in those tables. How else can you show the genre of a movie?

Comment: how can i insert data into a one-to-many relationships table? i tried it and it shows me some errors. A query example for inserting value for the users_movies table would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added an example.